# How do I keep a variable from a previous line of text in a while loop (perl) for another section of code?

Tags: perl, text

I am new to Perl and was not able to find an answer to this specific problem. I am parsing some text. I would like some of the entries from a line to be used as input for other lines. In the below I would like $sec to be used for messages that start with "M".
My code is as follows:

```
#identify the type of message here:
my $message = substr $_, 0, 1;

if ($message eq "T") {

    my $sec = substr $_, 1, 5;

    #no ms entry here
    my $ms = 66666;

    push @add_orders, $_;
    print add_order_file "$sec, $ms\n";  
}

if ($message eq "M") {

    my $ms=substr $_, 1, 3;
    push @add_orders, $_;

    #I want $sec to be from the previous 
    print add_order_file "$sec, $ms \n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `$sec` variable before and outside the loop, that way the value can persist between iterations.

```
my $sec;

# The loop - I've guessed it's a while loop iterating over lines in a file.
while ( <> ) {

    my $message = substr $_,0,1;

    if ( $message eq "T" ) {
        # Assign to $sec here
    }
    if ( $message eq "M" ) {
        # Use $sec here
    }

} # End of the loop.
```

There's a lot of assumptions being made here: if there are multiple `M`s after a `T` they all use the same `$sec` value, etc.